# Debugging compiled function in ASP .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a website I believe to be in ASP .NET, which is throwing an exception `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`. Stack trace shows as follows:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   SomeScript.getConnection() +32
   SomeScript.buildGridData() +299
   SomeScript.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +92
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +43
   System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e) +0
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +163
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +163
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2603
```

Same error is occurring for basically all pages of the site which request data, with just the `SomeScript` in above stack trace alternating for the loading script.

Environmental changes have only been in changing password for a remote SMTP server the site uses for mailing out, but site was continuing to load fine after that change was made.

My feeling is that these errors with the getConnection() method started occurring after a user tried to use said SMTP mailing function within the website and received an error (I was not able to capture the error user received).

I'm a bit lost with debugging any further from here as the getConnection() method seems to be within compiled DLLs and not accessible by me.

What is the next step in trying to remove the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it's unlikely that an SMTP password change has caused the issue from your description of it. But if that password change was made in the `Web.config` file, I'd say it's possible it was made less carefully than it should have been, and in fact a database connection-related section in there has been inadvertently modified and is no longer valid.

If you want to be able to debug into the DLL, you can disable the option to debug "Just My Code" in Visual Studio (something like Tools/Options/Debugging) - you should then be able to step down into these DLLs and see where the issue lies. Hopefully it won't require any code changes, and you can just fix up the configuration file.

Comment: Thanks. My love of IIS continues, as simply opening the web.config file, making some changes, reverting and saving alleviated the issue. It is possible someone had edited the file as you say, trying to change the SMTP info and fudging up the db connection.